# Temperature evolution of a Heated Sphere (high Biot number)

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, time-evolution

A homogeneous sphere is uniformly heated (or cooled) while the boundary is kept at constant temperature.

How does its temperature evolve in time and how is it distributed spatially?

Comment: At high Biot number, the surface temperature of the sphere approaches that of the external medium.  So, in the limit, the behavior is the same as if you suddenly changed the surface temperature to the external medium temperature at time zero.

Comment: So a case of quenching then?

Comment: More like what it takes for the heat transfer coefficient to be high, like having a rapidly flowing stream flowing by or with condensing vapor on its surface.

Comment: High heat transfer coefficient or low thermal diffusivity: that's how $\Pi$ numbers work, is it not?

Comment: I think what you mean is low thermal conductivity.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Haste makes waste.

Comment: I finally corrected that now.

Answer (score 1):

**Temperature evolution in time and space of an internally Heated Sphere**

(In P.SE tradition I'll provide my [own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to this question)

**Newton's Law of heating or Fourier's Heat Equation?**

- In the case of a low [Biot number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot_number):

$$\text{Bi}=\frac{Rh}{k}$$

(where $R$ is the radius, $h$ the convection coefficient and $k$ the thermal conductivity) internal temperature gradients $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$ will be small and Newton's Law of heating (so-called 'lumped thermal analysis') can be used.

- But when $\text{Bi}$ is high, spatial temperature distribution becomes uneven and we need to use Fourier's Law of heat conduction.

For a sphere with complete symmetry, we're looking for a function $u(r,t)$ that satisfies:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\alpha}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)+q$$
with $q$ the heat source. Boundary and initial condition:
$$u(R,t)=0\text{ and }u(r,0)=f(r)$$
(Attentive readers may now wonder about a 'missing' boundary condition)
where $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity: $\alpha=\frac{k}{\rho c_p}$.

Developed and using shorthand:
$$u_t=\frac{2\alpha}{r}u_r+\alpha u_{rr}+q\tag{1}$$
The problem now is that $(1)$ is **not homogeneous**, so separation of variables doesn't work here.

To try and homogenise it we define:
$$u(r,t)=u_E(r)+v(r,t)$$
where $u_E(x)$ is the **steady state** temperature, for $u_t=0$:
$$u_t=0 \Rightarrow u_E(r)$$
From $(1)$:
$$\alpha ru''_E+2\alpha u'_E+qr=0$$
Which solves to:
$$u_E(r)=\frac{c_1}{r}+c_2-\frac{qr^2}{6\alpha}$$
Note that:
$$r\to 0 \Rightarrow u_E(0)\to +\infty \Rightarrow c_1=0$$
(this was our 'hidden' boundary condition)
$$r=R\rightarrow u_E(r)=\frac{q}{6\alpha}(R^2-r^2)$$
Now remember that:
$$u(r,t)=u_E(r)+v(r,t)\tag{2}$$
Let's calculate some derivatives:
$$u_t=0+v_t$$
$$u_r=u'_E(r)+v_r$$
$$u_{rr}=u''_E(r)+v_{rr}$$
$$u'_E=-\frac{qr}{3\alpha}\Rightarrow u''_E=-\frac{q}{3\alpha}$$
Insert it all into $(2)$:
$$u_t=\frac{2\alpha}{r}\left(-\frac{qr}{3\alpha}+v_r\right)+\alpha \left(-\frac{q}{3\alpha}+v_{rr}\right)+q$$
$$\Rightarrow v_t=\frac{2\alpha}{r}v_r+\alpha v_{rr}$$
So the PDE in $v(x,t)$ is **homogeneous**.
Checking also the boundary condition:

$$u(R,t)=u_E(R)+v(R,t)=0\text{ with } u(R,t)=0 \Rightarrow v(R,t)=0$$

So the boundary condition **remain homogeneous**.

Separation of variables can now be executed. Ansatz:
$$u(r,t)=R(r)\Theta(t)$$
$$\frac{\Theta'}{\alpha \Theta}=\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{R'}{rR}=-\lambda^2$$
$$\frac{\Theta'}{\alpha\Theta}=-\lambda^2$$
$$\Theta(t)=\exp(-\alpha\lambda^2 t)$$
$$\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{R'}{rR}=-\lambda^2$$
$$rR''(r)+R'(r)+\lambda^2rR(r)=0$$
This solves to:
$$R(r)=c_1J_0(\lambda r)+c_2Y_0(\lambda r)$$
Where $J_0$ and $Y_0$ are the Bessel functions.

Note that for:
$$r \to 0 \Rightarrow Y_0 \to -\infty \Rightarrow c_2=0$$
$$R(R)=0=J_0(\lambda_n R)$$
$$\lambda_n R=z_n$$
The roots $z_n$ of the first Bessel function are:

[image: Roots of Bessel function]
$$R(r)=c_1J_0(\lambda_n R)$$
$$u_n(r,t)=C_n\exp(-\alpha\lambda_n^2 t)J_0(\lambda_n R)$$
With the superposition Principle:
$$u(r,t)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n\exp(-\alpha\lambda_n^2 t)J_0(\lambda_n R)$$
Initial condition:
$$u(r,0)=u_E(r)+v(r,0) \Rightarrow v(r,0)=f(r)-u_E(r)$$
$$v(r,0)=f(r)-u_E(r)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_nJ_0(\lambda_n R)$$
So that:
$$C_n=\frac{2}{R}\int_0^R\left[f(r)-u_E(r)\right]J_0(\lambda_n R)\text{d}r$$
Putting it all together:
$$\boxed{u(r,t)=\frac{q}{6\alpha}(R^2-r^2)+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n\exp(-\alpha\lambda_n^2 t)J_0(\lambda_n R)}$$