# Heat transfer / dissipation

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a hollow cylinder made of material A (eg. glass).
Inside the cylinder I have some liquid (material B, eg. water).

On the outside of the cylinder, wrapped around it, I have a metal wire (material C, eg. copper).
We use the resistance of the wire with the appropriate current to generate heat.

All parameters are known apriori (room temperature, materials' temperature, volume, etc.).

**The questions:**
(1) Paramterically, how do I calculate the time it takes to heat the material inside the cylinder to
a target temperature?
(2) Similarly, once I turn off current to the wire, how long for the material inside the cylinder to cool down to a target temperature?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a complicated situation that involves consideration of fluid flow and heat transfer within the liquid.   There are going to be natural convection currents and conductive heat transfer, and the temperature is not going to be uniform throughout the liquid.  You need to have some experience with fluid mechanics, heat transfer, and numerical analysis to solve this one (in my opinion).  However, there are ways of bounding the answer to give you the maximum possible amounts of time required to reach the desired temperatures.

Comment: If the content of  the cylinder was solid, the solution would be easier (but not necessarily *very easy* either, see this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/567929/heat-absorbed-from-a-reservoir-by-a-moving-object/567945#567945 overview post of mine) However, with liquid inside the cylinder temperature gradients and convection currents are very hard to account for.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thank you for the quick reply! How would you go about bounding the maximum possible amount of time? 

Also, in principle, is there a closed form solution to this problem?

Comment: I would start out by looking at solutions to the transient problem of constant heat flux to a cylinder of material by radial conduction, making some allowance for the glass.  Carslaw and Jaeger, Heat Conduction in solids.  This would eliminate the enhancing effects of the natural convection.

Comment: @ChetMiller Hi Chet. Want to run something by you unrelated to this post. In working on an answer to another post I encountered the following on the Chemistry exchange: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119656/entropy-changes-during-transfer-of-heat-between-two-bodies  I agree with your answer but would like to take it one step further to determine the lost work opportunity due to the entropy generated. Would I be correct in multiplying the generated entropy by the temperature at the interface of 400K (the final equilibrium temperature)?

Comment: @BobD I have to think about this for a while.  Lets continue this discussion in PF.

Comment: @Chet Miller Thanks, that would be great. I’ll initiate it.

Comment: @BobD 
I haven't worked it out in detail, but I think the answer you arrived at is correct if you have a supplementary reservoir at 400 K to work with that can be situated such that two Carnot engines can be run between each of the bodies and the reservoir.. The net heat received from this reservoir would be the work. But, in this case, the internal energy of the reservoir would change.