# Quantum particle moving on the surface of cylinder

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian

I have a problem with a spinless particle moving on the lateral surface of a cylinder of radius $r$.

If no Hamiltonian is given, is $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ only?

What are the Hamiltonian's eigenfunctions and eigenvalues?

Do I have to write down the Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates?

I've tried as follows:

$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ so in cylidrical coordinates the TISE is:

$\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial z^2}\psi(z,r)+\frac{L_z^2}{r^2}\psi(z,r)=E\psi(z,r)$ since $L_z^2=-\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \phi^2}$ the Hamiltonian in separable and I can find a solution of the form $\psi(z,r)=F(z)R(r)$ and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You need a potential term in your Hamiltonian to stop the particle from leaving the cylindrical surface.

Comment: @CameronGibson What is the form of this potential term?

Comment: I think that it would be best to clarify things about your question: are we ignoring gravity, is the particle moving on the inner or outer surface of the cylinder, what are the initial conditions, do you want a classical or quantum description? Also, it might be helpful to give any context to this question and why you asked it.

Comment: @CameronGibson Title: 'Quantum particle'.

Comment: Is the particle perhaps *contained* inside the cylinder, with $\infty$ potentials at the lateral surface of the cylinder and $0$ potential inside of the cylinder? Some clarification is definitely needed.

Comment: @Gert The particle is inside the lateral surface and could only move on the surface with 0 potential inside the cylinder, ignoring gravity. It is the analogous problem to the particle moving on the spherical surface in which spherical harmonics are used but on a cylinder.

Comment: @Salmone Ok, understood. Not terribly hard. Have you tried?

Comment: @Gert Yes, I will add my solution in the first question.

Comment: @Salmone Cylindrical coordinates are three: radius $R$, length $Z$ and angle $\varphi$. I'll formulate a solution a bit later on. It will take time though.

Comment: @Gert I discarded the part in $r$ because the radius is constant.

Comment: $r$ is NOT the radius. Call the cylinder's radius $R_o$ (e.g.) then $r$ is the *radial position of the particle* (the distance from the axis of symmetry)

Comment: @Gert The particle only moves on the surface of the cylinder, not in the whole volume.

Comment: *The particle is inside the lateral surface and could only move on the surface with 0 potential inside the cylinder, ignoring gravity.* Firstly, gravity is always ignored in these problems. But the potential cannot be 0 inside and the particle be restricted to moving on the lateral surface, at the same time. With 0 potential inside, there's nothing keeping the particle on the surface.

Comment: Do you mean a 2d cylinder in 3D space?

Comment: @Felicia $3D$ space.

Comment: The solution is a direct product of quantized states of motion around the cylinder, and continuous states in the length (z).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but it seems the question is simply 'what are the eigenfunctions of a quantum particle confined to the (lateral) surface of a cylinder?'. There is no need to add an infinite potential to the Hamiltonian in order to confine the particle to the surface. For instance, when you solve the problem of a free particle in a 'box' in 2D, one does not add an infinite potential to confine the particle along the 3rd dimension. For simplicity, I will take the radius of the cylinder to be $R=1$. I'll also be assuming that question is about the scenario in which the cylinder is infinitely long.

There is no motion along the radial direction $r$, but there is motion along $z$ and $\phi$. The Hamiltonian given by Salmone is almost correct. It is ($\hbar=1$)
\begin{equation}
 H = -\frac{1}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}  -\frac{1}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2},
\end{equation}
which is clearly separable. The eigenfunctions are then given by $\psi(z,\phi) = Z (z) \Phi(\phi)$, where $Z$ and $\Phi$ are the states of a free particle, i.e.,
\begin{align}
Z(z) &= e^{ikz}\\
\Phi(\phi) &= e^{ik\phi},
\end{align}
where I'll let you worry about the correct normalisation of these functions.
For $Z$, the values of $k$ are any real number, while for $\Phi$ we have $\Phi(\phi+2 \pi) = \Phi (\phi)$, which implies that $k = 0, \pm1,\pm2, \dots$.

Then the corresponding eigenvalues for either $Z$ and $\Phi$ are simply $E = k^2/2m$ (where $Z$ and $\Phi$ have different constraints on the possible values of $k$)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can't the particle move around the cylinder too? I agree no infinite potential is needed. In a 2D square these are needed though to keep the particle  within the confines of the square. These are absent in the case of a cylinder. It's like a particle moving on a cylinder like in Kaluza-Klein theory.

Comment: @Haydn Thanks, just one question: if the cylinder is infinitely long, don't we have problems in normalizing $Z(z)$?

Comment: @Haydn Why the solution of $\Phi(\phi)=e^{ik\phi}$ and not $\Phi(\phi)=e^{-ik\phi}$?

Comment: @Felicia I'm not sure I quite understand your question. We have just decomposed the particle motion along $z$ and $\phi$, so it can still move around the cylinder, right?

Comment: @Salmone there are variety of different approaches you could take for the normalisation along $z$. A standard approach would be to consider that the cylinder length is $L$ and then to take cyclic boundary conditions along $L$ [i.e., $Z(z) = Z(z+L)]$. This is then a normalisable problem and in the limit of $L \to \infty$, the possible values of $k$ effectively become continuous.

Similarly, taking $\Phi(\phi)=e^{I k \phi}$ is effectively a matter of convention. Replacing $k\to -k$ won't change anything due to the nature of our k values $k = 0, \pm1, \pm2, \dots$.

Comment: I misunderstood "There is no motion along the radial direction r" But as I see now, the particle can move in 2 directions.

Comment: @Felicia ah great! And good spot about the connection to Kaluza-Klein theory :)

Comment: Great answer by the way! I already gave you +1:)

Comment: @Haydn So, if the cylinder lenght is $L$ we have a infinite potential well along $z$ and we can easily normalize the eigenfunctions, if the cylinder lenght is infinite, we have a free particle along $z$.

Comment: @Salmone, yep that is correct. I'll just point out that it is slightly more standard to enforce periodic boundary condition along $z$ (rather than zero boundary conditions, which is enforced by an infinite potential) but ultimately as you take $L \to \infty$ this won't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

**Quantum Particle trapped in a Cylindrical Well**

I'll solve this problem more or less *'ab initio'*'.
Since as $U=0$ inside the cylinder and $+\infty$ outside of it, the TISE is (with $u$ - which saves keystrokes - the wave function):
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 =Eu$$

With the $\nabla^2$-operator in cylindrical coordinates:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{u_r}{r}+u_{rr}+\frac{u_{\varphi \varphi}}{r^2}+u_{zz}\right)=Eu$$
The Boundary Conditions, because $U=\infty$ outside of the cylinder ($R_o$ outer radius, $L$ length of cylinder):
$$u(R_o,\varphi, z)=0$$
$$u(r,\varphi,0)=u(r,\varphi,L)=0$$
We assume that:
$$u(r,\varphi,z)=R(r)\Phi(\varphi)Z(z))$$
Now carry out *separation of variables*:
$$\frac{u_r}{r}+u_{rr}+\frac{u_{\varphi \varphi}}{r^2}+u_{zz}=-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}u\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{\Phi Z R'}{r}+\Phi Z R''+\frac{RZ\Phi''}{r^2}+\Phi R Z''=-k^2u$$
$$\frac{R'}{rR}+\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{\Phi''}{r^2\Phi }+\frac{Z''}{Z}=-k^2$$

$$\frac{R'}{rR}+\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{\Phi''}{r^2\Phi}+k^2=\frac{Z''}{Z}=-m^2$$
Here's the first ODE:
$$\frac{Z''}{Z}=-m^2\tag{2}$$
$$\frac{R'}{rR}+\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{\Phi''}{r^2\Phi}+k^2=-m^2$$
$$\frac{rR'}{R}+\frac{r^2R''}{R}+\frac{\Phi''}{\Phi}+k^2r^2=-m^2r^2$$

$$\frac{rR'}{R}+\frac{r^2R''}{R}+k^2r^2+m^2r^2=-\frac{\Phi''}{\Phi}=\ell^2$$
And the second ODE:
$$\frac{\Phi''}{\Phi}=-\ell^2\tag{3}$$

$$\frac{rR'}{R}+\frac{r^2R''}{R}+k^2r^2+m^2r^2=\ell^2$$
Finally:
$$r^2R''+rR'+\left((k^2+m^2)r^2-\ell^2\right)R=0\tag{4}$$

---

From $(2)$ and the first BC we glean:

$$Z_n(z)=A\sin m_nz$$

$$m_n=\frac{n\pi }{L}\text{ for }n=1,2,3,...$$

$(3)$ looks very similar to $(2)$ but $\varphi$ is an angle, so it has $2\pi$ periodicity. We get:
$$\Phi_{\ell}(\varphi)=B e^{i \ell \varphi}$$
$$\ell=0,1,2,3,...$$
$(4)$ solves to:
$$R(r)=C_1 J_{\ell}\left(r\sqrt{k^2+m^2}\right)+C_2  Y_{\ell}\left(r\sqrt{k^2+m^2}\right)$$
Because:
$$Y_{\ell}\to -\infty\text{ for }r \to 0 \Rightarrow C_2=0$$

$$R(r)=C_1 J_{\ell}\left(r\sqrt{k^2+m^2}\right)$$
So using the first BC:
$$0=J_{\ell}\left(R_o\sqrt{k^2+m^2}\right)$$
If we call the roots of the Bessel function $J_{\ell}$ the values $\rho_{\ell,m}$, then:
$$\rho_{\ell,m}=R_o\sqrt{k^2+m^2}$$
$$\rho_{\ell,m}^2=R_o^2(k^2+m^2)$$
$$k^2=\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}$$
$$E_{\ell,n}=\hbar^2\frac{\rho_{\ell,m}^2L^2-n^2 \pi^2 R_o^2}{2m R_o^2 L^2}$$
You can find the values of  the $\rho_{\ell,m}$ [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/567370/temperature-evolution-of-a-heated-sphere-high-biot-number/567371#567371).

We get the energy levels. Note that these are not nicely geometrically spaced like for the $\text{1DPB}$ or the hydrogen atom.

---

If you're interested in probability densities, the solutions to $(2)$, $(3)$ and $(4)$ would need to be **normalised** on their respective domains (not shown).